# How can I convert a whole directory tree into uppercase filenames and directory names with bash/awk or similar?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, filenames

for matching purposes I would need to convert a whole big filesystem (filenames and directory names) into upper case letters. It would be great if we could create links to the orig filenames where the linkname should be the same as the orig filename but in UPPERCASE. Moreover the dir.-tree for the links should also be the same but in UPPERCASE again.

Have anyone here have an idea how this can be handled?
Thanks a lot.

Thanks for the advice below. I could do it now this way,but it is still buggy.
And I can not find it fast. Any idear where the bug is?

```
    #! /bin/bash

    walk () {
        local dir=$1
        cd "$dir" || return
        local f
        for f in .* * ; do
            if [[ $f == . || $f == .. ]] ; then
                continue  # Skip the special ones
            fi

            if [[ $f == *[[:lower:]]* ]] ; then  # Skip if no lowercase
                mkdir -p "$2""/""$dir" && ln -s "$(pwd)""/""$f" "$2""/""$dir""/""${f^^}"
            fi
            if [[ -d "$f" ]] ; then
                walk "$f" "$2"
            fi
        done
        cd ..
    }

    walk "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: `echo "$pathname" | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"`

Comment: What should happen if files `fileA` and `FileA` exist in the same directory?

Comment: Maybe think about improving the code that does the matching...

Comment: thank you very much, I can improve and learn, I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function.

I use the ^^ parameter expansion so I don't have to shell out to `tr`, it should be faster.

```
#! /bin/bash

walk () {
    local dir=$1
    cd "$dir" || return
    local f
    for f in .* * ; do
        if [[ $f == . || $f == .. ]] ; then
            continue  # Skip the special ones
        fi

        if [[ $f == *[[:lower:]]* ]] ; then  # Skip if no lowercase
            ln -s "$f" "${f^^}"
        fi
        if [[ -d "$f" ]] ; then
            walk "$f"
        fi
    done
    cd ..
}

walk "$1"
```

You'll probably get some errors, for example when `FILE` and `file` exist in the same directory, or if the directory can't be entered.

Comment: thanks, one more question. I would like to write the new UPPER case links into a separate directory. Your solution writes the links in the same position. How can your solution be adapted to meet my requirements again?

Comment: Maybe prepend a `$prefix` before `${f^^}`, or replace a known intial part of it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had needed some time to interpret your smart code!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, something like this will keep them together in arrays:

```
original_pathnames=()
uppercase_pathnames=()

pathname="/path/to/my/file.ext"

#I suppose you could put this into a loop where you pass a giant list of files (find?)
########################################################################################

original_pathnames+=("$pathname")
uppercase_pathnames+=("$(echo "$pathname" | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]")")

########################################################################################
```

chorboda made a good point.  This will conflict during your matching process if you have 2 files making a case insensitive match.  You will have to handle that case as well, but this is a good start.  I'm not sure where you are getting your directory tree list from either.  I would use `find` to get the list of files, then loop through with `IFS=$'\n'`, but if you are using `find`, the `-iname` flag will do a case insensitive search for you.